# How to find the generating function and the closed form for the generating form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, closed-form

I'm trying to find the generating function and the closed form for the generating form for this sequence:

$0,1,-2,4,-8,16,-32,64...$

I've tried the following:

I think it's an index shift so that's why the generating function is:
$a_n= $?

What about the closed form? 
Can you please tell how I solve this, and not only the result.

Comment: With the exception of the initial term of $0$, it's just $a_n = (-2)^n$.

Comment: Try $t/(1+2t)$.

Comment: @mapierce271 : $$-2^2$$ isn't 4 but -4

Comment: @Mr.H123 You have absolutely no basic informations about math. Please, start from scratch. [It is 4](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-2%29^2).
$$(-2)^2 = (-2)\cdot(-2) = 4$$
And please don't understand it as an attempt to insult. I just don't know how to help you, as long as you do not have such informations. I worry about you. Over time, the more problems will arrive.

Comment: Sorry... I know, but it was just what my calculator gave me. Meant $$-2^0$$ It's not 1 but -1

Comment: I think I agree with Tacet that these are the sorts of arithmetic operations that you need to be able to handle correctly with ease before you can tackle a topic like generating functions.  Try not using a calculator to compute the powers of $-2.$  A rule you should know is that $a^0=1$ for any $a\ne0.$  (The expression $0^0$ is undefined.)  You should also know that whole number exponents mean repeated multiplication.  So $(-2)^1=-2,$ $(-2)^2=(-2)(-2)=4,$ $(-2)^3=(-2)(-2)(-2)=-8,$ and so on.  You should be careful about parentheses.  Expressions like $-2^2$ are interpreted as ...

Comment: $-(2^2)=-4,$ and not as $(-2)^2=4.$  Some calculators with unary minus may be exceptions, but it pays to use explicit parentheses when unsure.

Answer (score 3):

The generating function is
$$
g(x)=0+1\cdot x-2x^2+4x^3-8x^4+16x^5-\ldots.
$$
Observe that each coefficient starting with the coefficient of $x^2$ is $-2$ times the coefficient of the previous term.  This suggests the idea of multiplying $g(x)$ by $-2x$ and subtracting the result from $g(x).$  If you do this, you will find that all terms cancel but one.  So you have $g(x)-(-2xg(x))$ equals the leftover term.  You should then be able to solve for $g(x)$ algebraically.

Comment: So it's: $$A(x)=0+1x-2x^2+4x^3-8x^4+16x^5-32x^6+64x^7$$ ?

Comment: ^^The generating form

Comment: In your post, you wrote the sequence as $$0,\ 1,\ -2,\ 4,\ -8,\ 16,\ -32,\ 64\ldots,$$ which led me to believe that the sequence was infinite.  Why do you terminate the sequence with the $x^7$ term?  Is it actually a finite sequence?

Comment: No it's infinite

Comment: Just tried to follow my teachers way of solving such sequences

Comment: Well, $A(x)$ should be in infinite sequence, not  polynomial.  I can't help much without knowing where you are getting stuck.

Comment: The generating function is $$(-2)^n$$ but this doesn't give 0 or 1 (these are from the sequence)

Comment: The expression $(-2)^n$ is not the generating function.  It is a (not quite correct) formula for the terms in the sequence.  A generating function for the sequence $a_0,$ $a_1,$ $a_2,$ $a_3,$ $\ldots$ is $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\ldots.$  Such an expression with an indeterminate $x$ is known as a formal power series.  Your sequence is $a_0=0,$ $a_1=1,$ $a_2=-2,$ $a_3=4,$ $\ldots.$  You need to multiply these numbers by appropriate powers of $x$ and sum the resulting terms to get a generating function.  The formula you give does have the problem you mention: it doesn't produce the initial ...

Comment: ... term, $0.$  Another problem is that the index is off by $1.$  So $a_2=-2$ but $(-2)^1=-2$.  Similarly $a_3=4$ but $(-2)^2=4.$  So $a_n=(-2)^n$ is not a true statement.  To get a correct formula, you need to modify the exponent slightly.  With this correction, the formula will be correct for all elements of the sequence except $a_0.$  (It will even work for $a_1$ since $(-2)^0=1.$)  You can't really write a simple formula that works also for $a_0,$ so I would just make that a special case.  This exception at $a_0$ is easier to deal with in the generating function context.